# How to deal with multiple null or undefined values when any object or field can be null? like this <p>{{object.object2.object3.field1}}</p>

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

```
<p>{{object.object2.object3.field1}}</p>
```

I have many `<p>` filled with objects that have an object which have an object that might have field and in any case `object` or `object2` or `object3` or `field` can be `null` or `undefined`. How to deal with this correctly?

If I try to put an `ngIf` for each and every value my view will get crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try below,

```
<p>{{object?.object2?.object3?.field1}}</p>
```

Read more about [Safe navigation operator here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add if you want that in case var is null or undefined and you want to put a place holder such as "--" or "missing" you can do it like this:

`<p>{{object?.object2?.object3?.field1 || '--'}}</p> //Shows '--' if missing field1 or objects`

It can even be mixed with pipes:

`<p>{{(object1?.object2?.object3?.dateField | date: 'shortDate')  || 'Missing date'}}</p>`

Displays: Missing date if null or undefined